# How to split decimal number into two TextView in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am Working on this android application development project. I want to spit decimal number like 2.91 into two `TextViews`, each `TextView` takes part of the number
like first `TextView` takes the 2 and second `TextView` takes the 91 without the decimal points

Here is my Code:

**Test.Java**

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btSpilt;
EditText Input;
TextView wholenumber, points;
private double d;
private long a, b;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    btSpilt = findViewById(R.id.Test);
    btSpilt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            double d = Input.getText();

            long a = (long) d;
            double f = d - a;

            while (Math.abs((long) f - f) > 0.000001) f *= 10;

            long b = (long) f;

            wholenumber.setText((int) a);
            points.setText((int) b);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Activity_test.xml**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="input"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="76dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btSpilt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Split"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="146dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wholenumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Whole Number"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="244dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/points"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Points"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You must do some research on your part before posting a question on SO. :) You can simply use the text from EditText and then split the String using a regex. So you can use `Input.getText().toString().split(".")` to get an array of 2 strings containing the two numbers respectively.

Comment: What is your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow.
If i understand correctly, Your concrete problem is that you want to split the input double into decimal and whole part.
You can get it done in following way:
`String[] number = Input.getText().toString().split(".");`

So you can rewrite your method like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    String[] number = Input.getText().toString().split(".");

    wholenumber.setText(number[0]);
    points.setText(number[1]);
}
```

However you'll notice that `number[1]` might return `null` for non-decimal numbers. So you might need to take care for this particular case.

Hope this helps